# Current working directory being pre-pended to to import statement, breaking the path

Tags: android, ant

I'm attempting to setup my own custom build script to build a release version of my Android app.  The project root build.xml file generated by Android SDK works as expected and produces a release build.  What I'm trying to do now is write other custom build scripts which call this build.xml file after doing some pre and eventually post processing.  I don't wish to modify the build.xml script.  The scripts look like this:

MyCustomScript1.xml imports .../MyAndroidProjectRoot/build.xml like this:

```
<import file="../build.xml"/>
```

This project root build.xml file in turn imports the build.xml file from the tools directory of the SDK like this:

```
<import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml" />
```

However my problem is that the import is failing (as denoted by a warning message in MyCustomScript1.xml build.xml import statement) with this message:

> Cannot find /home/cknight/workspace/application/MyAndroidProjectRoot/${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml imported from  /home/cknight/workspace/applicatoin/MyAndroidProjectRoot/build.xml

I cannot access the targets in the skd buld.xml file from MyCustomScript1.xml

Why is the current working directory being pre-pended to the import statement in the project root build.xml file and how can I fix this?

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this problem?